# Download of a folder as a whole?

Tags: ubuntu-one, macosx, macbook

I occasionally use Ubuntu One for purchase music; I would like to find a way to import my music from the cloud to my MacBook (which of course is not running Ubuntu). I wonder if, for this purpouse, I must download each track individually, or if there is a way to download a whole folder (tipically, the album).

Many thanks in advance ;)

Comment: Duplicate of this bug report on Launchpad: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntuone-servers/+bug/819246

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is something we want to do, but have not yet managed to squeeze into our schedule.
The next 5 months have been decided, but we'll try and squeeze it in after the 11.04 release.

Comment: This going to be supported soon?

Comment: @Martin Albisetti it's been about a year and half since your comment. Does Ubuntu One now support this feature? If so where can I find out about it, if not when is this expected?

Answer (score 3):

Why is your MacBook "of course" not running Ubuntu?  It's perfectly possible to run Ubuntu on it, either natively or in a virtual machine.  :)

Anyway, currently the only way to download your music from the web interface in one go is by making an archive (.tar.gz or .zip or whatever) on your Ubuntu system first.

There is a [bug about this feature](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntuone-servers/+bug/612014) on Launchpad; near the top you can indicate that it affects you too.

Comment: Right, I have also Ubuntu under Virtualbox on my Mac; but I do prefer to avoid using a virtual machine only to download my files. Many thanks for letting me aware of the Launchpad page!