# How do I download a whole Ubuntu One folder?

Tags: 10.04, ubuntu-one, firefox

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Download of a folder as a whole?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/8698/download-of-a-folder-as-a-whole)

Due to problems with 11.10 I just went back using 10.04. I thought it would be no problem since my files are all on Ubuntu one. On 10.04 I seem only to be able to access my files though Firefox and can only download them one by one.

IS there a way to download a whole folder back to my desktop

Answer (score 2):

You could use the desktop client. Just start Ubuntu One, and let it sync.

If you don't want to keep on syncing it afterwards, you can remove your computer from the authorized devices list.

Answer (score 0):

If you have uploaded files to your Ubuntu One cloud storage and are now setting up a new computer or re-installing your operating system, it's important to not copy over the following folder from a backup copy you may have saved: *~/.local/share/ubuntuone*

As long as you do not copy that folder over, you are safe to setup Ubuntu One on your computer as you normally would following the setup instructions.